# How do I find matching filenames in a directory listing?

Tags: bash, grep

I have bunch of ISO images in my hdd and I have their whole content listed inside a text file in the following format:

```
<immage>.iso, <dir structure>/<filename>.<extension>
```

example:

```
OS Backups.iso, ­ubuntu-­12.­04-­desktop-­i386.­iso 
OS Backups.iso, xubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso
OS Backups.iso, background/pictures.jpg
Pictures vacation 2011.iso, documents/cost_estimates.xls
Pictures vacation 2011.iso, italy/img1.jpg
Pictures vacation 2011.iso, italy/img2.jpg
```

Now I want to issue a grep command against that text file to find files that contain "pictures" in their names. The expected result would be (for the previous example):

```
Pictures vacation 2011.iso
OS Backups.iso, background/pictures.jpg
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish something like this using grep? Alternatives? Thanks!

Comment: a bash script would do as well, ideas?

Comment: Maybe I don't get something? Why `grep -i pictures file.txt` isn't enough for this?

Comment: He wants the if in first half just give the iso, if in second half give the full line logic.

Comment: Can I ask, how you will use the information afterwards. For example, will you read it later on to import to some system in a specific format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how to do it with *grep*, using Perl regular expression syntax `-P`, and the *return-only-matching-part* switch `-o`:

```
grep -Poi "(.*pictures.*\.iso.*pictures.*|.*pictures.*\.iso|.*pictures.*)"  | sort | uniq
```

which returns:

```
OS Backups.iso, background/pictures.jpg
Pictures vacation 2011.iso
```

- for each line, `grep` first checks if it's an `.iso` files with "pictures" in its name, **which also contains** a file with "pictures" in its name, e.g.:

  ```
  Pictures vacation 2011.iso, italy/pictures5.jpg
  ```
- If it finds, it prints the line and moves on; if not, it checks if this is an `.iso` files with "pictures" in its name;
- If so, it prints just the ISO name; if not, it checks if this line contains a file with "pictures" in its name...

Comment: Good point.  I hadn't considered the having pictures on both sides.

Comment: although other solutions would do the job, this is the shortest and clearest of all. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk -F ", " 'BEGIN { IGNORECASE=1 } $1 ~ /pictures/ { print $1 ; next } $2 ~ /pictures/ { print }' < context.txt | sort | uniq
OS Backups.iso, background/pictures.jpg
Pictures vacation 2011.iso
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re, sys
a_file = sys.argv[1]
a_string = sys.argv[2]

#from http://www.peterbe.com/plog/uniqifiers-benchmark
def uniquify(seq, idfun=None): 
   # order preserving
   if idfun is None:
       def idfun(x): return x
   seen = {}
   result = []
   for item in seq:
       marker = idfun(item)
       # in old Python versions:
       # if seen.has_key(marker)
       # but in new ones:
       if marker in seen: continue
       seen[marker] = 1
       result.append(item)
   return result

mylist = []

with open(a_file, 'r') as items:
    for line in items.readlines():
        if (re.search(a_string, line, re.IGNORECASE)):
            temp = line.split(',',1)
            if (re.search(a_string, temp[0], re.IGNORECASE)):
                mylist.append(temp[0])
            else:
                mylist.append(line.rstrip())

mylist = uniquify(mylist)
for item in mylist:
    print(item)
```

Produces the desired output when run as `python test.py index.txt pictures`

Answer (score -1):

```
import fileinput
import sys
lookFor = sys.argv[1]
for line in fileinput.input("textfile.txt"):
    if lookFor in line:
            print line
```

You can run this script with `python scriptName.py WORDTOLOOKFOR`
For example, if I want to check for a line in the textfile containing the word "ubuntu", and the script is named script.py I write the following

```
python script.py ubuntu
```

Be sure to rename the textfile in the script.

Edit: This will only print the lines containing it, not store it anywhere, much like what grep can do.

Comment: your #!/bin/bash line is not correct.  i edited in sys.argv in the other python answer

Comment: if it were `chmod +x`-ed and run directly it would fail. it also doesn't address the entire point of not just using `grep -i`

Comment: I'm not talking about this any more.  You're stating that the file should be interpreted by bash.  It shouldn't.  It's python

Comment: I agree with aking1012: either remove the misleading shebang line or change it so that the kernel can invoke your python program with a python interpreter.